# How does the VS Code Python "justMyCode" debugger feature determine which code belongs to the user?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Visual Studio Code offers a debugger launch option called [justMyCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode) which allows - if set to false - to step-into non-user written code when debugging. The documentation says:

> When omitted or set to true (the default), restricts debugging to
> user-written code only. Set to false to also enable debugging of
> standard library functions.

But this doesn't seem to include only Python standard libraries. For example, if we install and use the popular PIL image library...

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("./image.jpg")
```

...and set a breakpoint at line 2, we are able to step-into the non-user-code `Image.open()` method.

Based on which criteria does VS Code know that PIL is non-user code? The path the package resides in?

Comment: follow the path of the setting in the source code, do you need to debug this feature, a similar question is: "How does the setting `jinja2` work?". I don't care it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the code you wrote and the path where the import package is located.

Vscode can distinguish the code by identifying the path